# Why QML MediaPlayer/VideoOutput doesn't work for me?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtmultimedia

I'm trying to play test video with qml by this code:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtMultimedia 5.0

Item {
    width: 300
    height: 300

    MediaPlayer {
        id: player
        source: "C:\\Downloads\\video.mp4"
    }

    VideoOutput {
        id: video
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: player
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onPressed: player.play()
    }
}
```

But, when I click on view, nothing happens. And if I change `onPressed` event to something else action (not with the `player`), it works fine, then it's not a `MouseArea` problem.

Where did I wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file path seems to be wrong. Since baclslashes need to be escaped in string litterals, the actual path remaining is:

```
c:\Downloads\video.mp4
```

That's a path, but not an URL. The correct URL is (see [File URIs in Windows](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows.aspx)):

```
file:///C:/Downloads/video.mp4
```

Answer (score -1):

On your code source:

```
C:\\Downloads\\video.mp4
```

should be source:

```
C://Downloads//video.mp4
```